# How to conjugate multiple adjectives using て-form with conflicting tenses?

Tags: て-form, adjectives

I know how to say something when both adjectives are the same tense, such as:

> あの　人　は　かわいくて　ちいさい　です。 That person is cute and small.

However, how would you say something like, "That person is cute and not small"? Would it be:

> あの　人　は　かわいくて　ちいさくない　です。

Is this even possible, or would you have to split the sentence up so that the tenses match?

Please write answers in hiragana or romaji, please! I am still an elementary Japanese learner.

Comment: Typically, using spaces, the sentence would look like this: あの人は　かわいくて　ちいさいです.

Comment: I think your 2nd sentence could be confusing, just as saying "That person is not short and cute."  Is s/he cute or not?  I'd think that ちいさくなくてかわいい would be clearer.  Just as "cute but not short" makes it clearer what's being negated.

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, you're not asking about tenses, you're asking about positives vs. negatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> あの人は　かわいくて　ちいさくない　です。

As far as grammar goes, this sentence is already fine. It literally means "That person is cute and not small."

However, this sentence looks a bit odd to me, because people don't often associate cute things with large things. On the other hand, "ちいさくて かわいい (cute little)" is used almost as a set phrase, far more often than "おおきくて かわいい".

So I would say this sentence would look more natural and clear if you say:

> - あの人は　かわいい**けれど**　ちいさくない　です。 That person is cute **but** is not small.
> - あの人は　ちいさくない**けれど**　かわいい　です。 That person is not small **but** is cute.

Compare:

> - あの人は　かわいくも　ちいさくも　ない　です。 That person is neither cute nor small.
> - あの人は　かわいかったり　ちいさかったり　しません。 That person is neither cute nor small.